# Maximum recommended daily intake of full fat milk for 12 year old?

Tags: nutrition, health-education, milk

What is the maximum recommended daily amount of full fat milk for a 12 year old boy, assuming an average weight for 12 year olds at 40kg (88lb). Is 1.5 english pints per day too much?

Comment: What do you mean what would happen? It's just milk.

Comment: An infant can safely drink 2 pints of breast milk (4.4% fat) per day. Anyway, "safe" sounds like "not dangerous," so it is a strong word in this context. Healthy?

Comment: no, phiysycicly to the point it can cause side effects. And @carey Gregory milk contains high levels of fat so can cause blood to become acidic

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: @LeoCornelius, drinking milk has an alkaline effect. You can search for milk-alkali syndrome, which does not develop after 1.5 pints of milk, anyway.

Comment: @LeoCornelius you can and should edit your question, if you want to add new information or clarify the given ones. If you give important content in a comment, it might get lost in the future or people just don't read it.

Comment: I'm the downvoter and I did comment. It's just milk. It's a food like many others with no reason to suspect that it's unsafe to drink in reasonable quantities, which 1.5 pints per day certainly is for a healthy 12-year old.

Comment: I believe the question is legitimate and of real concern for many parents, so I see no reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Jan Currently the Q is a bit on the low quality side, broad & vague, lacking prior research, etc. You yourself had to ask for clarification. The box underneath explains that with an [edit] this might be salvaged. Who does the edit is unimportant, that an edit improves the Q is.

Comment: I have edited my question and have done research and have found the answer so if you could reopen it I could post it to help others.

Comment: @LeoCornelius I voted to re-open – *despite* the Q still being in need of further improvement. Can you balance your research for the answer as to splice something of your research effort into the question? (Your assumptions about "acidity" might fit?)

Comment: @LeoCornelius - The question is open. Please pay attention to the requests for improvement in the question by several of the commentors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found no credible source that would mention "maximum recommended daily amount of full fat milk."

[MedlinePlus](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001973.htm):

> The US Department of Agriculture recommends the following daily
>   amounts of dairy for children and teens:
>
> - Two through 3 years old: 2 cups (480 milliliters)
> - Four through 8 years old: 2½ cups (600 milliliters)
> - Nine through 18 years old: 3 cups (720 milliliters)

A 12 year old boy drinking 1.5 US pints (710 milliliters) of milk fits in.

Regarding the concern that milk can make blood acidic: The acidogenic effect of foods can be estimated by "renal acid load" (the amount of acids secreted through the kidneys). According to [this article (Table 2)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5490517/), renal acid load after one serving (240 mL) of full fat milk is 3.6, and after low-fat milk 3.9, which means it is not fat in the milk that contributes to the acidity. Renal acid loads of certain other foods are much higher: one serving of cheese (17-57), meat (14-21), fish (10-32), nuts (16-36).

According to one [2015 systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4504608/), milk consumption does not seem to contribute to kidney stones.

There is an ongoing debate if milk is healthy or unhealthy and there are opinions that milk is only for children (or even only for small children). Most of research shows that milk consumption as such is not bad for health ([PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5143456/)). On the other hand, plant-based diets may be healthy enough, even for children ([PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2912628/)).

Comment: You need to make it clear that the 1.5 pints you mentioned for 12 year olds is 1.5 US Pints as that is 1.25 UK Pints because we use the imperial pint measure

Comment: OK.............

Comment: Stick to metricals, all of you :P @Chris

Comment: I am metricated for some measurements but not all.  It is good to see someone providing for both :-)